Matrix defined in terms of a characteristic function has positive eigenvalues
Let $\mu$ be a Gaussian measure over a Hilbert space $F$ its characteristic function:
$$F(f) = \int e^{i\langle \phi, f\rangle} d\mu(\phi)$$
and define the following matrix:
$$M_{ij} = F(f_i)F(f_j) e^{\langle f_i, Cf_j\rangle} = F(f_i)F(f_j)N_{ij}$$
where $C$ is the covariance operator of the Gaussian measure and the $f_i \in H$. The claim is that $M_{ij}$ has positive eigenvalues if and only if the matrix $N_{ij}$ has positive eigenvalues. How can one see this?

This is a combination of four facts:

For a Gaussian measure $\mu$, the characteristic function only takes strictly positive value, i.e., $F(f) > 0$ for any $f$ ($F(f)$ being nonzero real is enough for our purposes);
If $\{r_1, \cdots, r_n\}$ is a list of real values, then the matrix $K_{ij} = r_ir_j$ is positive. This can be seen by noting that an $n \times n$ real symmetric matrix $K$ is positive iff $\langle \xi, K\xi \rangle \geq 0$ for all $\xi \in \mathbb{R}^n$. And, indeed, if $\xi = (s_1, \cdots, s_n)^T$, then $\langle \xi, K\xi \rangle = \sum_{i,j} s_ir_ir_js_j = (\sum_i s_ir_i)^2 \geq 0$. In particular, $F_{ij} = F(f_i)F(f_j)$ and $G_{ij} = F(f_i)^{-1}F(f_j)^{-1}$ are both positive matrices;
The Schur product theorem, which says the Hadamard product of two positive matrices is positive. Here, the Hadamard product of two $n \times n$ matrices $P_{ij}$ and $Q_{ij}$ is defined by $(P \odot Q)_{ij} = P_{ij}Q_{ij}$;
Both $M_{ij}$ and $N_{ij}$ are easily seen to be real symmetric matrices. For such matrices, by spectral theorem, they have only positive eigenvalues iff they are positive. Recall that $F_{ij} = F(f_i)F(f_j)$ and $G_{ij} = F(f_i)^{-1}F(f_j)^{-1}$ are both positive matrices. Thus, $N_{ij}$ has only positive eigenvalues iff $N_{ij}$ is positive, which implies $M_{ij} = F(f_i)F(f_j)N_{ij} = (F \odot N)_{ij}$ is positive, so $M_{ij}$ has only positive eigenvalues. Conversely, $M_{ij}$ has only positive eigenvalues iff $M_{ij}$ is positive, which implies $N_{ij} = F(f_i)^{-1}F(f_j)^{-1}M_{ij} = (G \odot M)_{ij}$ is positive, so $M_{ij}$ has only positive eigenvalues.


Thank you! What forbids the characteristic function from taking imaginary values?

@CBBAM I’m understanding Gaussian measure to mean centered Gaussian here. In particular, $d\mu(\phi) = d\mu(-\phi)$, so$$\overline{F(f)} = \int\overline{e^{i\langle\phi, f\rangle}},d\mu(\phi) = \int e^{-i\langle\phi, f\rangle},d\mu(\phi) = \int e^{i\langle-\phi, f\rangle},d\mu(\phi) = \int e^{i\langle\phi, f\rangle},d\mu(-\phi) = \int e^{i\langle\phi, f\rangle},d\mu(\phi) = F(f)$$

Thanks again for all your help!
